# How to find the html tag using its attribute and its text both in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I got a tag, let's say

```
<td columnname="ID">DS199</td>.
```

Now I have to find this tag using selenium on the basis of attribute **columnname** and the **text** of the tag both.
The code I have used:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@columnname='ID' AND (text()='DS199')]"));
```

Output:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException:invalid selector: Unable to locate the element with the xpath expression //td[@columnname='ID' AND (text()='DS199')]
```

Please let me know the correct way to get the webelement object when multiple conditions are to be validated on the tag.

Comment: is the element visible? is it inside an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Maybe you have some leading or trailing space in your text

```
"//td[@columnname='ID'][normalize-space(text())='DS199']"
```

Comment: This will work, but you glossed over the true issue by switching to multiple predicates rather than one predicate with a conjunction of conditions: OP had the case of `and` wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's `and`, not `AND`:

```
//td[@columnname='ID' and (text()='DS199')]
```

Also, you might want to test the string value of the `td`:

```
//td[@columnname='ID' and .='DS199']
```

if you'd like to also match, say

```
<td columnname="ID"><b>DS199</b></td>
```

or, somewhat more robustly if you'd like to normalize whitespace,

```
//td[@columnname='ID' and normalize-space()='DS199']
```

Comment: @Grasshopper: No, I did not; it's the default.